# Comparing DateTime's Isn't Working

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that logs the processes of a computer and then from that initial time, every X minutes after, another log is saved in a text file. I've got the writing to the text file and everything going fine. I just can't seem to get DateTime to work properly or I'm misunderstanding its uses.

```
DateTime firstTime = DateTime.Now; 

Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
{
    sw.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
sw.WriteLine(firstTime);


DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
sw.WriteLine(now);
while (DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now)
{
    DateTime nuw = DateTime.Now;
    sw.WriteLine(nuw);
    if (nuw == now)
    {

        sw.WriteLine("It worked");
    }             
}
```

I know the while loop is terrible, but I was just seeing if anything could work. The problem that I think is causing this is that DateTime.Now, doesn't update/change every second, it remains the same throughout the entire duration. Even going console and writing it out endlessly, it remains the same date that was first called.

So yea, I'm at the end of what I know what to do.

Comment: `while(DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now)` is equivalent to `while(true)`

Comment: such bad solution... in theory DateTime.Now has also milliseconds but the cost of doing an == is so low that it probably always happens in the same millisecond. just rewrite your while condition.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a timer that fires every X minutes to achieve your task. Your while loop will lock the UI of your program and eat a lot of CPU.

Comment: Whoever downvoted me: Please leave a comment, explaining your reasons. I can't fix my answer without it.

Comment: +1. A timer is definitely a better way to go than hogging the CPU like this. Unless repeatedly calling sw.WriteLine() is really needed...

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the explanation should be that while correct, this isn't what was asked. Also, this appears to be a console program, so it can't really *freeze*.

Comment: I assumed that his console program was meant as a proof of concept. Also, his question shows that he is a beginner. IMHO it is not a good thing to always answer the exact question as asked by a beginner. It is better to show him a better way to do the thing he wants to achieve. His intention is to log something every X minutes. And that's what I helped him with.

Comment: I appreciate it. I still don't have it working, even with the solutions provided of if(now.CompareTo(nuw) < 0) and (nuw >= now). Is there a specific tutorial that I could read that goes over timers and possibly for this kind of a situation? Not sure if I'll find the right tutorial on Google.

Comment: @Alex: I think the following tutorial gives a good overview: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/sample_chapter/article.php/c7763

Answer (score 1):

The comparision `==` on `DateTime` compares the internal ticks. A tick is 100 ns or one ten-millionth of a second, there are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond. In constrast, windows runs with a cycle time of about 20ms. The comparision is like trying to find a needle in a haystack the size of the universe.

Use `(nuw >= now)` instead, it compares for exact match or after now.

Comment: Not correct. `nuw` is assigned the value of `DateTime.Now` in every iteration of the while loop!

Answer (score 1):

The System.Threading.Timer class should do the trick. You will have to provide a using for the System.Threading namespace.

```
    static public void ListProcesses(Object stateInfo)
    {
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create a callback to our worker method
        TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(ListProcesses);

        // create a one minute timer tick
        Timer stateTimer = new Timer(callback, null, 0, 60000);

        // loop here forever
        while (true)
        {
            //sleep every second so we dont hog the cpu
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            //add program control logic
            //if we want to exit the program with anything other than closing the window
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like

```
if(now.CompareTo(nuw) < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing for equality on time is kind of like trying to split an arrow in archery. Getting exactly one minute out isn't likely.

I think you want `if (nuw >= now)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok from my perspective the biggest thing you're causing yourself problems with is your variable naming, unless i'm missing something - always use clear variable names so that your code reads out naturally.

The use of a timer as shown above is certainly an excellent way of solving your problem, however i'll continue and keep in with the theme of the code you've written since the author of the timer answer has covered that one very well.

I must admit also tend to be very shy of "while(true)" loops as i'd rather have a more proactive control of stopping the app, usually via Start() and Stop() methods and an _isRunning variable - where the _isRunning is what goes in as your loop condition. For simplicity however i'll stick with a while(true).

So, rewritten slightly, your loop would look like this:

```
DateTime timeOfNextOperation = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
Console.WriteLine(timeOfNextOperation);
while (true)
{
    if (DateTime.Now >= timeOfNextOperation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do Stuff Here");
        timeOfNextOperation = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

You absolutely must put some kind of yield (a sleep of some kind) in to your loop or you will use 100% cpu in a tight loop.  Even a sleep of 1ms makes a huge difference but think hard about whether you really *need* it to spin that fast - in this case, it certainly doesn't, you're only doing something once every minute spin every second is more than adequate.

Your loop also did not reset it to make it happen *every* minute, the above does, by setting the time of the next operation.  Note that in this example i'm setting it AFTER i've done my task (in this case, print a line :) ) - this means that it will run with a 1 minute gap between each execution, NOT every minute - i.e. if the task takes 30 seconds then it will happen at 1 minute, then 2 minutes 30 seconds.  If you put the task AFTER then it will schedule to run 1 minute after it starts running, so it will run at 1min then 2min, the danger is that if your task ever takes more than 1 minute then it will spin straight back in to it again.

As a general rule, never compare just with the end of a range, always compare with <= or >= - in some cases it's not necessary (eg. if you're stepping through a loop one at a time you're not likely to miss the last one) however it is a good habit to get in to so that you can't end up with cases where you didn't realise it *could* skip one.

All the above said I do agree that the Timer is your best bet, the only optimisation i'd make to infomaniac's excellent code sample is that you don't need to create the delegate reference, it's implicit in the newer versions of .NET .

i.e.

```
Timer stateTimer = new Timer(ListProcesses, null, 0, 60000);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for everything you explained. It was awesome to have a better grasp.

Comment: I'm having an issue though. When I use Using System.Threading; or Using System.Timers, in any combination that I use these, I get an 'ambiguous reference'. I eventually concluded that that is probably because I was trying to do this in a form class/button (I had to do it in a windows form application, not console), so I thought I should put all of the methods and such in the Programs.cs, and that was all working until I tried to use Using System.Management;

 It wouldn't become detected in any new project I made, and would only work in the original console project. Am I like over my head now?

Comment: No I don't think so, but possibly best posting this as a new question so that you can provide a more complete example of the code you're using as you're now taking a different approach that you're finding problems with.  I'm certain it's solvable :)